# Differentiation of a unit step function?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, dirac-delta

How come differentiation of a unit step function is Dirac Delta? Can anybody give me a concrete mathematical proof? I only found some intuitive kind of explanation, that at $t = 0$, slope of $u(t)$ increases rapidly, thus derivative at $t = 0$ becomes a Dirac Delta Function. Please give a concrete mathematical proof. Thanks.

Comment: For rigor, you need to know about the theory of distributions. In standard calculus, this derivative just doesn't exist.

Comment: @AlexM. Good point. I edited the title of the latter question to make it better searchable, and voted to close the former as a duplicate of it.